# Leaflet heatmap based on value not quantity

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, leaflet, heatmap

I got some thousand points containing weights. 
Many of those points have (more or less) the same coordinate and I want to visualize those points on a leaflet map using absolute coloring of the map. (Same coloring for a point at every zoom level)
I tried using leaflet.heat but it seems to be adding up the values (resulting in everything colored red) and does relative rendering.

It would be ideal if it would use the average or maximum of the provided weights for rendering a heatmap.

Anyone has an idea how this could be done quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach would be to use Leaflet-MarkerCluster, use a custom cluster symbolizer, and symbolize each cluster with the symbol corresponding to the point with the highest  value of the property.

Another approach would be to use Turf.js to hexbin the data in the client and apply the highest value to the hex.

Another approach would be to use a Voronoi tesselation, and symbolize each area of the tesselation with the desired value, optionally clipping the symbols to prevent symbolizing large empty areas.